# How to find element locators using selenium webdriver java for AngularJS UI applications

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium

How to write xpath for AngularJs applications using selenium webdriver java

Comment: Have you checked with Karma , Jasmine and Protractor  for Testing of Angular Application ?

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question is incomplete, the answer is:

You can either use protractor
Or you can use xpath expressions and make sure you have sufficient explicit waits for finding the elements as angular will give you timing issues otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use plain Selenium for testing Angular applications. [Protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) just makes it easier to test Angular application. Its a framework for testing Angular applications.

It has Automatic Waiting for elements and you can access specific Angular elements `by.model` and `by.binding`. Also it implements the Page Objects in the framework making tests more maintainable if used correctly.

But if you already have a selenium-based e2e testing framework in place - you can use it also for AngularJS web-apps. You can also write the necessary JavaScript scripts that, once ran using the webdriver - will let you do all that Protractor does - but you'll have to do it yourself .

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly you want to `write` **`xpath`** `for webdriver to work with` **`AngularJS UI applicatons`**.

Here is the complete procedure with **`Google Chrome`** and **`Firefox Quantum`** :

### Example Usage :

Now, let us assume we have to identify the `xpath` of the **`Search Box`** on `Google Home Page`.

1. Open `Mozilla Firefox Quantum` browser or `Google Chrome` browser and browse to the url `https://www.google.co.in`
2. Press **`F12`** to open the `Development Tools`
3. Within the `Development Tools` section, on the `Inspector` tab, use the `Inspector` to identify the `Search Box` WebElement.
4. Copy the `xpath` (absolute) and paste it in a text pad.
5. Construct a logical unique `xpath`.
6. Within the `DevTools` section, on the `Console` tab, within `JS` sub menu, paste the logical unique `xpath` you have constructed in the following format and hit `Enter`/`Return`:

   ```
   $x("logical_unique_xpath_of_search_box")
   ```
7. Example: To find the `Search` Box on `Google Home Page` try :

   ```
   $x("//*[@name='q']")
   ```
8. The `WebElement` identified by the `xpath` will be reflected.
9. Example : The following will be returned back on the Console :

   ```
   Array [ input#lst-ib.gsfi ]
   ```